# How do I find text between 2 characters?

Tags: notepad++, find-in-files

I have a notepad++ file with lots of lines. How do I find specific text if I know it's between @ and @ starts with G, ends with R and is 18 characters long?

So for example I wanna find this: 
G8G8v8AGGtVGR8VRXR

out of this:
kjfoih6fn@PVIJF928G5@G8G8v8AGGtVGR8VRXR@VKJEOIHGQP5V4R4frg97etrg@53qvhF

The actuall file is much bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Check the regular expressions box in the find/replace dialog (CTRL + H) then use a regular expression to match what you are looking for like

```
@G[^@]{16}R@
```

Comment: Where is the test for exactly 18 characters?

Comment: ah, didnt see that part i fixed it in the edit now

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your case you can write more or less strict regular expressions (press CTRL+F in notepad++ then check regular expression box):

- [`(?<=@)G.{16}R(?=@)`](https://regex101.com/r/jGeAzM/1) - - will find 18 characters (G+16+R) between two `@` starting with G ending in R; result will exclude `@`s
- `@G.{16}R@` - the same with `@`s
- `@G.*R@` will just look for the text between @G and @R without considering length
- ...

Comment: the . in there should be [^@] otherwise the expression would match something like @GHKJ@JKNNDK@NKJNJR@

Comment: @SE I don't see anywhere described that it can't contain @

Comment: technically not but it's implicit in the problem definition

Comment: Thanx worked great.